# How can I check if tablespace exist in DB2 z/os

Tags: db2, procedure

How can I check if tablespace exist in DB2 z/os.

I have to create table RMPOLICY

My task is create script for update database. Update will create table and auxiliary table.

For that task I have to make 4 steps:
1. create tablespace for table 
2. create tablespace for auxiliary table
3. create table 
4. create auxiliary table

I will be great if I can check all this step for completed before. It posible to check if table exist with

```
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO V_ALREADY_EXIST FROM SYSCAT.TABLES WHERE UPPER(RTRIM(TABNAME)) = UPPER(RTRIM('RMPOLICY'));
```

But I don't know how to check if tablespace exist.

Can you please help to determin this information from script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for [`SYSIBM.SYSTABLESPACE`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sysibmsystablespacetable.dita?cp=SSEPEK_10.0.0%2F10-0-112).